# How do I use the CHCSV parser?

Tags: objective-c, csv

I am new to the programming world and learning iPhone app development. For one of my apps, I am downloading CSV data from Yahoo finance. I want to have it in a dictionary. After some searches, I found the CHCSV parser. My question is how to use it?

I copied the files into my project and tried its different methods. I know my approach is kind of silly. As a novice in these things, I would really appreciate it if someone can help me out. In the following code I am initializing a CHCSV object by passing in the CSV file. I guess the `parse` method is the right one to use. After that, I have no clue how to get a dictionary out of it.

```
#import "ifinance5ViewController.h"
#import "CHCSV.h"

@implementation ifinance5ViewController

@synthesize button1;

-(IBAction)buttonpressed:(UIButton*)sender{
    NSString *locfile = @"/Users/---/Desktop/array.csv";
    NSError *anError = nil;

    [CHCSV *csvfile]=[[CHCSV alloc]initWithContentsOfCSVFile:(NSString *)locfile usedEncoding:(NSStringEncoding *)NSASCIIStringEncoding error:(NSError **)anError];
    [csvfile parse];
}
```